# Caching Instantiated Object

Tags: object, caching, coldfusion-10

I am trying to cache a block of code that instantiates two objects (the primary object extends the generic abstract one.

Without the cache-specific code everything works fine. But when I run the below code I only get a blank page. I'm unsure if this is expected behavior but I doubt it.

I'm calling this like so:

**test.cfm**

```
 <cfset foobar = CreateObject("foo") />

        <cfset foobar.pushLeads(
            a = 1,
            b = 2
        ) />
```

**foo.cfc**

```
<cffunction name="pushLeads" access="public" returntype="void">
        <cfargument name="a" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="b" required="true" />

    <cfset local.cachedVendorData = cacheGet("vendorExport") />

            <cfif IsNull(local.cachedVendorData)>

                <cfsavecontent variable="local.vendorCFC">
                    <cfset local.leadsObj = createobject("baz").init() />

                    <!--- Take leads and pass into cfc for pushing to remote server --->
                    <cfset test =  local.leadsObj.pushLeadData(
                        a = arguments.a,
                        b = arguments.b
                    ) />

                    <cfdump var="#test#">
                </cfsavecontent>
                <cfoutput>#local.vendorCFC#</cfoutput>
                <cfset cachePut("vendorExport", local.vendorCFC, CreateTimeSpan(0,0,1,0))>

            </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

**Edit** - I forgot to add before that, before caching I had a CFDUMP that would show all results returned. Now that I added caching the dump results are not appearing.

Comment: You're setting a variable, but I don't see an output. Perhaps your code sample isn't showing enough.

Comment: I did omit. something. I modified the post above.

Comment: I don't see the cfdump examples. Please post more of (or full) code sample.